# Writing Custom Map Tools using RectangleMapTool

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-plugins, mapcanvas

I am creating a plugin with a preview window where the user must select a rectangle to define the study zone.

I see in this https://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/pyqgis_developer_cookbook/canvas.html the Writing Custom Map Tools example but I do not know how to call it and give the possibility to the user to draw the rectangle.

I put this code in the .ui dialog python script:

```
class RectangleMapTool(QgsMapToolEmitPoint):
    def __init__(self, canvas):
        self.canvas = canvas
        QgsMapToolEmitPoint.__init__(self, self.canvas)
        self.rubberBand = QgsRubberBand(self.canvas, True)
        self.rubberBand.setColor(Qt.red)
        self.rubberBand.setWidth(1)
        self.reset()

    def reset(self):
        self.startPoint = self.endPoint = None
        self.isEmittingPoint = False
        self.rubberBand.reset(True)

    def canvasPressEvent(self, e):
        self.startPoint = self.toMapCoordinates(e.pos())
        self.endPoint = self.startPoint
        self.isEmittingPoint = True
        self.showRect(self.startPoint, self.endPoint)

    def canvasReleaseEvent(self, e):
        self.isEmittingPoint = False
        r = self.rectangle()
        if r is not None:
          print("Rectangle:", r.xMinimum(),
                r.yMinimum(), r.xMaximum(), r.yMaximum()
               )

    def canvasMoveEvent(self, e):
        if not self.isEmittingPoint:
          return

        self.endPoint = self.toMapCoordinates(e.pos())
        self.showRect(self.startPoint, self.endPoint)

    def showRect(self, startPoint, endPoint):
        self.rubberBand.reset(QGis.Polygon)
        if startPoint.x() == endPoint.x() or startPoint.y() == endPoint.y():
          return

        point1 = QgsPoint(startPoint.x(), startPoint.y())
        point2 = QgsPoint(startPoint.x(), endPoint.y())
        point3 = QgsPoint(endPoint.x(), endPoint.y())
        point4 = QgsPoint(endPoint.x(), startPoint.y())

        self.rubberBand.addPoint(point1, False)
        self.rubberBand.addPoint(point2, False)
        self.rubberBand.addPoint(point3, False)
        self.rubberBand.addPoint(point4, True)    # true to update canvas
        self.rubberBand.show()

    def rectangle(self):
        if self.startPoint is None or self.endPoint is None:
          return None
        elif (self.startPoint.x() == self.endPoint.x() or \
              self.startPoint.y() == self.endPoint.y()):
          return None

          return QgsRectangle(self.startPoint, self.endPoint)

    def deactivate(self):
        QgsMapTool.deactivate(self)
        self.deactivated.emit()
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to call your `RectangleMapTool` constructor somewhere in the plugin code and then set it as the current map tool for the canvas like this:

```
rectangleTool = RectangleMapTool(self.iface.mapCanvas())
self.iface.mapCanvas().setMapTool(rectangleTool)
```

If you also want to perform some action after the rectangle is drawn then you should implement a PyQt signal in `RectangleMapTool`.