# QgsMapToolEmitPoint(): argument 1 has unexpected type 'sip.wrappertype'

Tags: pyqgis

I have tried this code and several other similar versions and I always get this error
See [Writing Custom Map Tools using RectangleMapTool](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/376090/writing-custom-map-tools-using-rectanglemaptool)

```
QgsMapToolEmitPoint.__init__(self, self.canvas)
 TypeError: QgsMapToolEmitPoint(): argument 1 has unexpected type 'sip.wrappertype'
```

I just can't seem to find a solution..

```py
class MyMapTool(QgsMapToolEmitPoint):
    def __init__(self, canvas):
        QgsMapToolEmitPoint.__init__(self, canvas)
        self.rubberBand = QgsRubberBand(canvas, True)
        self.rubberBand.setColor(QColor(255, 0, 0))
        self.rubberBand.setWidth(2)

    def canvasPressEvent(self, e):
        point = self.toMapCoordinates(e.pos())
        self.rubberBand.addPoint(point)
        self.rubberBand.show()

    def canvasMoveEvent(self, e):
        point = self.toMapCoordinates(e.pos())
        self.rubberBand.movePoint(point)

    def canvasReleaseEvent(self, e):
        point = self.toMapCoordinates(e.pos())
        self.rubberBand.addPoint(point)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have not shown any code where you create an instance of your custom map tool, but I suspect that the cause of the error in your question lies there.
I am guessing here but maybe you tried to do something like this:

```py
map_tool = MyMapTool(QgsMapCanvas)
```

Passing `QgsMapCanvas` with no params, would give you that error (because if you run: `print(type(QgsMapCanvas))` in the Python console you will see that it returns `<class 'sip.wrappertype'>`).

The `QgsMapToolEmitPoint` class constructor expects a `QgsMapCanvas()` object, i.e. an instance of the class. If you are running this in the Python console and working with the main QGIS map canvas, you should retrieve it like `iface.mapCanvas()` (or probably `self.iface.mapCanvas()` in a plugin).

A couple of other issues with your code:

1. It is a good idea to store the `QgsMapCanvas` object passed to the map tool as an instance attribute (e.g. `self.canvas`).
2. The second argument of the `QgsRubberBand` constructor should be the geometry type you are going to use for the rubber band.

E.g.

```py
QgsRubberBand(canvas, QgsWkbTypes.PolygonGeometry)
```

Note that from 3.30 onwards, you should use:

```py
QgsRubberBand(canvas, Qgis.GeometryType.Polygon)
```

Below are a couple of working examples of map tools using different rubber bands. The first is click and drag rectangle rubber band, the second allows for digitising a polygon using multiple consecutive mouse clicks (with right-click to finish). Both of these example work when pasted into a blank editor in the Python console and run from there. See the end of this answer for an example of using these in a plugin.

Drag rectangle tool:

```py
class RectangleMapTool(QgsMapToolEmitPoint):
    def __init__(self, canvas):
        self.canvas = canvas
        QgsMapToolEmitPoint.__init__(self, self.canvas)
        self.start_point = None
        self.end_point = None
        self.rubber_band = None
        
    def canvasPressEvent(self, e):
        if self.rubber_band:
            self.rubber_band.reset()
        self.rubber_band = QgsRubberBand(self.canvas, QgsWkbTypes.PolygonGeometry)
        self.rubber_band.setStrokeColor(Qt.red)
        self.rubber_band.setWidth(1)
        self.start_point = self.toMapCoordinates(e.pos())
        self.end_point = self.start_point
    
    def canvasMoveEvent(self, e):
        if self.start_point:
            self.end_point = self.toMapCoordinates(e.pos())
            self.rubber_band.reset()
            r = self.get_rectangle()
            self.rubber_band.setToGeometry(QgsGeometry().fromRect(r))
                
    def canvasReleaseEvent(self, e):
        self.end_point = self.toMapCoordinates(e.pos())
        r = self.get_rectangle()
        self.rubber_band.setToGeometry(QgsGeometry().fromRect(r))
        self.start_point = None
        self.end_point = None
        
    def get_rectangle(self): 
        rect = QgsRectangle(self.start_point, self.end_point)
        return rect
        
    def deactivate(self):
        if self.rubber_band:
            self.rubber_band.reset()
            
map_canvas = iface.mapCanvas()
map_tool = RectangleMapTool(map_canvas)
map_canvas.setMapTool(map_tool)
```

Draw polygon tool:

```py
class PolygonMapTool(QgsMapToolEmitPoint):
    def __init__(self, canvas):
        self.canvas = canvas
        QgsMapToolEmitPoint.__init__(self, self.canvas)
        self.rubber_band_line = None
        self.rubber_band_fixed = None
        self.points = []
        self.drawing = False
        
    def canvasPressEvent(self, e):
        set_point = self.toMapCoordinates(e.pos())
        if self.rubber_band_fixed:
            self.rubber_band_fixed.reset()
        if e.button() == Qt.LeftButton:
            self.drawing = True
            self.points.append(set_point)
            if len(self.points) == 2:
                self.rubber_band_fixed = QgsRubberBand(self.canvas, QgsWkbTypes.LineGeometry)
                self.rubber_band_fixed.setStrokeColor(QColor(255, 0, 0, 150))
                self.rubber_band_fixed.setWidth(2)
                geom = QgsGeometry().fromPolylineXY(self.points)
                self.rubber_band_fixed.setToGeometry(geom)
                self.rubber_band_fixed.show()
            elif len(self.points) > 2:
                self.rubber_band_fixed = QgsRubberBand(self.canvas, QgsWkbTypes.PolygonGeometry)
                self.rubber_band_fixed.setStrokeColor(QColor(255, 0, 0, 150))
                self.rubber_band_fixed.setWidth(2)
                pnt_ring = [p for p in self.points]
                pnt_ring.append(pnt_ring[0])
                geom = QgsGeometry().fromPolygonXY([pnt_ring])
                self.rubber_band_fixed.setToGeometry(geom)
                self.rubber_band_fixed.show()
        elif e.button() == Qt.RightButton:
            self.drawing = False
            if len(self.points) <= 2:
                self.clean_up()
            elif len(self.points) > 2:
                if self.rubber_band_line is not None:
                    self.rubber_band_line.reset()
                # Here you could create a QgsFeature instead of a rubber band
                pnt_ring = [p for p in self.points]
                pnt_ring.append(pnt_ring[0])
                geom = QgsGeometry().fromPolygonXY([pnt_ring])
                # and set the feature geometry to geom
                self.rubber_band_fixed.setToGeometry(geom)
                self.rubber_band_fixed.show()
                self.points.clear()
                
    def canvasMoveEvent(self, e):
        if self.drawing:
            point = self.toMapCoordinates(e.pos())
            if self.rubber_band_line is not None:
                self.rubber_band_line.reset()
            if self.points:
                self.rubber_band_line = QgsRubberBand(self.canvas, QgsWkbTypes.LineGeometry)
                self.rubber_band_line.setLineStyle(Qt.DashLine)
                self.rubber_band_line.setColor(QColor('Grey'))
                if len(self.points) == 1:
                    geom = QgsGeometry().fromPolylineXY([self.points[0], point])
                    self.rubber_band_line.setToGeometry(geom)
                    self.rubber_band_line.show()
                elif len(self.points) > 1:
                    geom = QgsGeometry().fromPolylineXY([self.points[0], point, self.points[-1]])
                    self.rubber_band_line.setToGeometry(geom)
                    self.rubber_band_line.show()
    
    def clean_up(self):
        if self.rubber_band_line is not None:
            self.rubber_band_line.reset()
            self.rubber_band_line = None
        if self.rubber_band_fixed is not None:
            self.rubber_band_fixed.reset()
            self.rubber_band_fixed = None
        self.points.clear()
        
    def deactivate(self):
        self.clean_up()
        
map_canvas = iface.mapCanvas()
map_tool = PolygonMapTool(map_canvas)
map_canvas.setMapTool(map_tool)
```

I have also packaged these into a minimal example plugin and uploaded to [GitHub repo](https://github.com/benwirf/map_tool_plugin). You can download a zip file using the green Code button and install it in QGIS to test it out.

Here is a short screencast showing the behaviour of the two map tools activated via the plugin:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, that appears to have solved the error but now the events ae not firing :(  That is not a problem for this thread.

Comment: Thanks again Ben, I was initially trying the linked example from the above, "PyQGIS Developer Cookbook 9. Using the Map Canvas".  In desperation, I tried the other copied I copied in the above code.  
I am calling just from a button on a plugin panel.

Comment: initially I was thinking to start with a rectangle but would have ultimately liked an irregular polygon.

Comment: You're an absolute champion - thanks